# Convert openVZ container to VMware

Tags: vmware, openvz

I'm trying to convert an openVZ container to VMware.
Since this is planned for roughly 1000 instances, I'm looking for a different approach than reinstalling from scratch.
I followed the steps in the last post:
https://communities.vmware.com/message/1719787#1719787
However, when booting from a live CD, it can't find any linux partition.
I also tried yum install kernel-xx which had no effect on the live CD not finding a partition so I'm assuming there's an error while converting.
Does anyone know of a solution or some tweaks to the one I posted?
The OS in this case is CentOS 7 on openVZ 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: Convert openVZ to KVM, then convert to VMWare.

- create a KVM with the same OS as your container
- mount the KVM image file
- rsync all data to that image file
- umount image file and start and stop KVM
- convert img to vmdk with qemu-img
- move vmdk file to esxi host
- convert to thin-provisioned vmdk with vmkfstools

I had to tackle (and still am) multiple issues to make it boot, like recrating initrams, reinstalling policykit, reconfiguring networking, adjusting grub.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will have to go the OpenVZ -> KVM -> VMware route. [This post by Roman Pertl](https://roman.pertl.org/2016/08/migration-of-openvz-container-to-kvm-guest/) explains how he did it, plus it also links to some other tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync --exclude=/var/lib/initramfs-tools/* --exclude=/var/lock --exclude=/etc/fstab --exclude=/etc/modules --exclude=/etc/mtab --exclude=/boot/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/lib/modules/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/sys/* -e ssh --delete-after --numeric-ids -avpogtStlHz / root@sourcevm:22/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).